# Is short lived access token and request token and authorization code the same thing?

Tags: oauth, access-token

Sorry for such dummy question but I search the web and still not sure to get these concepts correctly.

As I know oAuth v2 has these steps to authorize a user:

1- User requests to login with an oAuth provider (google,..) through client side (web browser or in a mobile app) of our application.

2- oAuth provider returns a request token to client side

3- client side sends this request token to server side

4- server side requests from oAuth provider to generate a long lived access token + refresh token (server sends app secret key with this request to verify itself)

5- server side can request any API in scopes defined from client side and permitted by user by this access token

6- server side should refresh the access token when the access token still is valid by sending refresh token to oAuth provider.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking Google specifically

**Step 1:**

The users is displayed a webpage where they can decided to grant you access or not

[image]

The scope of the access you can see in this instance is Google analytics Data, depend upon which scopes you ask the user for access to different things will be displayed here.

**Step 2:**

Assuming the user clicked Accept and granted you access you are given a `Authentication code`.

[image]

Authentication codes are not good for much.  They are probably short lived but I haven't tested this and haven't seen anything in the documentation on exactly how long you have to use them.

Update:  Authentication code is only good for one thing that is exchanging for the refresh token and access token.  Once you have done this the `Authentication code` is useless.  (Step 3)

**Step 3:**

Your system takes that `authentication code` sends it to the Authentication server along with your `client id` and `secret` again.   This time as a `HTTP POST`, the precious request was a HTTP GET.

The server will then return to you an Access token and a refresh token.

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

The access token is short lived it is good for 3600 seconds or one hour.  The refresh_token is good as long as the user doesn't revoke your access,  or it hasn't been used for 6 months I think, and that your application has been granted a max of 25 refresh tokens (need to double check that number for you )

You can use the access token to access the API at will for the next hour.

**(update)** The refresh token is used to get a new Access token after it has expired.

**step 4:**

After the hour is up and the access token no longer works, your system should  then take the refresh toke and request a new access token from the Authentication server.

**Further reading:**

If you want to see how to make the raw calls and what is returned check this tutorial [3 legged oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/)

and some light bed time reading [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

Comment: so is request token and authorization code the same thing? what about short lived access token? is short lived access token the access token part of that JSON you mentioned and is long lived token the refresh token?

Comment: No Authorization code is just a one time thing when the user accepts your access. Once you use it to get a Refresh token its never used again.     Short lived access token is the Access_token in the json its good for 1 hour, it is used to access the APIs.  Refresh_token is good as long as the user doesn't revoke your access and is used to get new Access tokens after they expire.

Comment: so where is the famous request token and long lived access token in this proccess?

Comment: If we are talking Google there is no such thing a long lived access token unless consider the api key for public APIs.   Not sure what you mean by request token, guess access token could be consider that.